# Determining from Objective-c if a Swift property is declared as dynamic

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have been trying for some time to inspect a Swift class, and determine if any of the properties are declared as dynamic.  My example class is as below:

```
class SwiftTestClass : DBObject {

    dynamic var SwiftTestString : String!
    dynamic var SwiftTestNumber : NSNumber!
    dynamic var lowercaseField : String!
    var nonDynamicVariable : String!

    func testThyself() {

        SwiftTestClass.query().fetchLightweight().removeAll()

        let newObject = SwiftTestClass();
        newObject.SwiftTestString = "hello, world"
        newObject.SwiftTestNumber = 123
        newObject.lowercaseField = "lowercase"
        newObject.nonDynamicVariable = "should not be persisted"
        newObject.commit()

        let result = SwiftTestClass.query().fetch().firstObject;
        print(result)

    }

}
```

I am basically trying to pick out the fact that the property `nonDynamicVariable` is not declared as dynamic as the rest of them are.

DBObject is a subclass of `NSObject`.

I have tried:

- Looking at the type encoding of the property, they are identical (type for type)
- Seeing if they have a difference in the method implementations, they do not. (e.g. `class_getMethod`), the dynamic properties still have getter/setter methods.
- Grabbing the Ivars to see if there is any difference there
- Looking at all of the property attributes, also identical.

What I do know:

- If I try to `class_replaceMethod` for the `<propertyName>/set<propertyName>`, it works for a dynamic property (as you would expect, because it adds objc compatibility) but fails to work (but does replace?, well, the memory address of the method changes!) or be actioned on the non dynamic property.

Does anyone know how to differentiate the two property declarations in swift from objc?

Thanks

Comment: Putting in the `dynamic` keyword guarantees that the compiler will use dynamic dispatch for the property.  However, omitting the `dynamic` keyword does not guarantee that the compiler will not use dynamic dispatch.  The choice to use static dispatch depends on many factors.  So I suspect you don't really want to differentiate the two declarations, but rather what the compiler chose to do.

Comment: But yes, possibly, that might be what I wanted to know.  The issue I have is that when Obj-c replaces the getter/setter methods on a swift object, these are obviously ignored if the property is not dynamically dispatched.  But, in legacy obj-c `@dynamic` was used by me to tell my framework that, this property is ripe for persistence whereas `@synthesised` properties were left alone as they already had the property methods attached.  This is pretty much exactly the same way that a `NSManagedObject` is/was setup and how changes to the property values were detected.

Comment: `@dynamic` was a hint to the compiler to let it know that an implementation was elsewhere (i.e., to not complain that you didn't provide one).  `@synthesize` was a hint to the compiler to generate the default getter/setter code for you.  In both cases these were dynamically dispatched (in fact, all method calls in Objective-C are always dynamically dispatched).